# Why does $.get trigger errorback on successful request

Tags: jquery

I have a simple ajax request for fetching an xml document that is successful according to Chrome dev tools (response is a 200 or 304 with the correct data), but triggers the `fail` callback afterwards for some reason beyond me.

```
$.get('foo.xml')
  .done(function (data) {
    $xml = $($.parseXML(data));
  });
```

Why would this be the case?

Comment: so what is the error you get in `fail()` callback???

Comment: So I was tripped up a bit because the first argument in the errorback was the xhr object, not the error itself...wish it was documented in the $.get documentation and not just $.ajax.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the error was an XML parsing error.

The documentation for `jQuery.get` does not mention the different input arguments that the errorback takes, but that information is found in the documentation for `$.ajax`.